# bean shell script in jmeter to extract id's from request response

Tags: parameters, request, jmeter, response, beanshell

what is the syntax for writing a bean shell script in jmeter to extract N number of values from a request response and passing the same into next request parameter?

Answer (score 1):

So, if you just want to extract some data from response of 1st request and pass it as request parameters to 2nd request-> You dont need to use beanshell and write code, Jmeter already provides a post processor called Regular Expression Extractor. Here you can write simple regex in Perl and give reference name as Param1. In your second request, just pass variable as ${Param1_g1}

Suppose your response is

```
<city>London</city>
```

and you want to extract London as pass it in another request, regular expression would be

```
<city>(.*)</city>
```

Comment: I tried this but it is for capturing single parameter. i need to capture multiple parameters in an array and pass it to further request. I was able to capture the parameter using **(.*?)** . But issue is it is stored in two dimensional array that what i was confused about.

Comment: Response: {"formId":"1234","formResponseId":"1","responseStatus":"a"},{"formId":"4567","formResponseId":"2","responseStatus":"b"},{"formId":"1234","formResponseId":"3","responseStatus":"b"},{"formId":"4567","formResponseId":"4","responseStatus":"b"}, i want to capture form response id which matches status b. similarly it has thousands of responses. First i need to store everything and the response id and status index values should match after storing in an array

Answer (score 0):

There are too many possible scenarios so no one can help unless you share more details, i.e. response (may be partial) and how should the next request look like.

In general:

- You have [Beanshell PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PostProcessor) and `prev` shorthand which stands for parent [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html) so you can use `prev.getResponseDataAsString()` method to access parent the sampler response body and extract what you need from it
- You have [Beanshell PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PreProcessor) and `sampler` shorthand which stands for this or that [AbstractSampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/AbstractSampler.html) implementation so you can manipulate the relevant methods and fields.

See [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) for more information on how to use JMeter API from Beanshell test elements with some examples.

Comment: Response: {"formId":"1234","formResponseId":"1","responseStatus":"a"},‌​{"formId":"4567","fo‌​rmResponseId":"2","r‌​esponseStatus":"b"},‌​{"formId":"1234","fo‌​rmResponseId":"3","r‌​esponseStatus":"b"},‌​{"formId":"4567","fo‌​rmResponseId":"4","r‌​esponseStatus":"b"}, i want to capture form response id which matches status b. similarly it has thousands of responses. First i need to store everything and the response id and status index values should match after storing in an array. It is getting stored in two dimensional array and further i want to evaluate for particular  status using IF loop.